# undefined method `authenticate' for #<Admin:0x99e67d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please am new to RoR, am trying to do an Admin authentication based on the name and password provided by the Admin.
Am using "RUBY ON RAILS TUTORIAL (RAILS 5)
Learn Web Development with Rails" by Michael Hartl, am on chapter 8; Basic login.
When i try to authenticate the user with the authenticate method it gives me this error message `undefined method authenticate for #<Admin:0x99e67d8>`

```
adminsessions_controller.rb

class AdminsessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
        admin = Admin.find_by(name: params[:adminsession][:name].downcase)
        if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:adminsession][:password])
          render plain: 'log in succesful'
        else
          render plain: 'log in failed' 
        end  
  end
end

admin.rb
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
```

end

Browser image
[Brower error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ3O6.jpg)

Comment: Do you have `has_secure_password` in your `Admin` model?

Comment: no i don't have any, its just the default, after generating the model with the rails generate model command

Comment: Well, you need it :)  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html